# WebRTC Node.JS WebSocket Server, Block a Request if WSS Parameter is Not 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, webrtc

I would like that the node Web Socket server (command: node /root/server.js) will refuse connection if **PARAM** is not 1. Connection like this will be refused: `wss://example.com/socket.io/?**PARAM**=**0**&EIO=3&transport=websocket`

server.js looks like this(EasyRTC Framework):
https://github.com/open-easyrtc/open-easyrtc/blob/master/server_example/server_ssl.js

I finally realized it's actually not that simple (doing inside server.js if PARAM != 1 then exit). Anyone can confirm this complexity or offer a simple solution, without recommending complex authentication frameworks. Also can't see that EasyRTC Framework will offer something like this.

Can someone lead me in the right direction because I am lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I crawled all the EasyRTC Group, there is an authentication system for node server.js web socket and it's very simple:

```
var onAuthenticate = function(socket, easyrtcid, appName, username, credential, easyrtcAuthMessage, next){
// do your checks
next(null); // Run next with a null if they are allowed in / or if not the socket is "disconnected" for them not for others.
};
easyrtc.events.on("authenticate", onAuthenticate);
```

Tested and works perfectly. More testing will follow.